# Filter dataframe and print in html by flask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask

I've a pandas dataframe with some analisis and need to filter and print in html by flask only X latest rows with upper or down arrows.

I am trying to make the code but I am making a tremendous mess between so much data and how to pass it to the html. I have this part but it doesn't work. Any idea to made it posible?

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    lastdates = 5
    product = {
        "brand":"Dyson",
        "model":"mod2019"
    }

    mod2019 = df['mod2019']
    result2019 = mod2019.tail(lastdates).values[0]

    if result2019 == '':
        product[brand][result2019] = ''

    elif result2019 == '':
        product[brand][result2019] = ''
    else:
        product[brand][result2019] = None

    return render_template('index2.html')
```

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>mod2019</th>
                <th>mod2020</th>
                <th>mod2021</th>
                <th>mod2022</th>
            </tr>
            {% for product in products %}
                {% if product[brand][result2019] %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ product }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ product[brand] }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ produc[brand][date] }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ produc[brand][result2019] }}
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

| Date | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-17 |  | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2021-01-18 | NaN |  | NaN |  |
| 2021-01-19 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2021-01-20 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2021-01-21 | NaN |  | NaN | NaN |
| 2021-01-22 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2021-01-23 |  | NaN |  | NaN |
| 2021-01-24 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2021-01-25 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

The result should be some like this.

| Product | Brand | Date | mod2019 | mod2020 | mod2021 | mod2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hairdryer | Dyson | 2021-01-21 |  |  |  |  |
| hairdryer | Dyson | 2021-01-23 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Have you looked at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?

Comment: Thanks! I don't know pandas html function. I will take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the variables that you are going to use in your template in your `render_template` function. Currently there are no variables being passed to your template.

In this example the variable `products`is going to be available in your jinja template:

```py
return render_template('index2.html', products=products)
```

```
{% for product in products %}
  {do something with product}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! My problem is how I can pass the dataframe data filtered to flask to only show the rows with arrows in this conditions.

Comment: The problem is in your approach, you are using if conditions in python to compare panda's data to a certain condition. Instead, you should use pandas to filter the data and only when the data is ready you should pass to flask to display it in a webpage. I can't help you write the entire code, but you should look for the pandas documentation and tutorials in order to better understand what to do.